# Removing mkoverlay from map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkoverlay

i added overlay (MKOverlay) with custom drawings to the Mapview. The overlay showing fine and i can see the drawings. But when i remove that overlay its not removing perfectly some part of the   drawing is still there. What is the reason? im using removeOverlay: for removing that overlay. Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if you guys are still wondering about this, but the following works for me:

```
// assuming you have mapView and overlay defined somewhere
MKOverlayView *overlayView = [mapView viewForOverlay:overlay];
overlayView.hidden = YES;
[overlayView setNeedsDisplay];
[mapView removeOverlay:overlay];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: great for those overlays that are off screen at the time of removing them.

Answer (score 2):

you can delete all overlay in your map. it's working very well

add this function to yourviewController :

```
-(void)deleteMapOverlays
{

    for (id<MKOverlay> overlay in mapView.overlays)
    {
        [self.mapView removeOverlay:overlay];
    }

}
```

using :

```
 [self deleteMapOverlays];
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting multiple overlays on top of my MKCircle() after the location was updated. Here's the Swift 4 answer of @ErhanDemirci answer with my MKCircle being added to it afterwards. Step 2. is the Swift 4 version of the answer.

```
// 1. add the MKCircle
let circle = MKCircle(center: location.coordinate, radius: whateverRadius)

// 2. loop through the map view's overlays then remove it. The overlay is the MKCircle
for overlay in mapView.overlays {
    mapView.remove(overlay)
}

// 3. add your the MKCircle to the mapView
mapView.add(circle)
```